# How to automate a tag for generating print-only and no-print Images in a specific Mediawiki skin?

Tags: images, mediawiki, print

I have multiple images in my wiki page that have to be set to 728px for the online version. I want these images to be printed with full resolution. I have long searched for a solution and in the end what I came to is this:

```
<span class="printonly">[[File:Audio-1.png]]</span>
<div class="noprint">[[File:Audio-1.png|728px]]</div>
```

The above is a code I use to embed the images into the wiki. But this means I have to change all the links to all the images I have, which can take quite a long time to achieve.
The question is, where in the skin php files (or how) I could write the code to automatically generate this code above when it sees:

```
[[File:Audio-1.png|728px]]
```

That should be easy to write, but I can't find the place where Mediawiki generates the Images from the tag above.